# Why my code doesn't work correctly when I put it into function?

Tags: php, function

I have a script named [`MakeAvatar.php`](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/3b1cd0a0acf86ab1601af5d16fbb415e) which generates a avatar *(something like stackoverflow's avatars)* based on two parameters:

- size *(it is size of avatar)*
- hash *(the shape and color avatar will be depends on this)*

Aslo I have this folder-structure:

```
\out
    MakeAvatar.php
\root
    \classes
        classname.php
    \img
        /* where images (avatars) are saved */
```

---

Now, there is two cases:

- When I use `MakeAvatar.php` out of function it works as well and the output will be a avatar which is saved as `.png` image:

**classname.php**

```
// these two parameters are changeable and these are just as an example
$size = 100;
$hash  = 'somettext';
require("../out/MakeAvatar.php");
```

Output:

[image]

---

- When I use `MakeAvatar.php` into function it doesn't work as well and the output will be a black image (which is identical for every parameter that will be sent )

**classname.php**

```
class classname{
    function index() {
        // these two parameters are changeable and these are just as an example
        $size = 100;
        $hash  = 'somettext';
        require("../out/MakeAvatar.php");
    }
}

$obj = new classname;
$obj->index();
```

Output:

[image]

---

What's wrong with it? And how can I fix it? Why when I warp `MakeAvatar.php` into a function, id doesn't create a correct avatar?

Here is [the errors](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/6bc4de3e20af08aadd9e50474075c665) I get when I put `MakeAvatar.php` into function.

Comment: show the code of `autoloader.php` and what means by (which is called by autoloader) , you are adding file with require than what is the usage of autoloader here. **TIP:** you must use `require_once`

Comment: so wher you have included `autoloader.php`? You are directly including `MakeAvatar.php` , instead of this you must use the autoloader.php and nore that it is case sesnsitive, you file name is MakeAvatar.

Comment: @diEcho `classname.php` is called by autoloader *(not `MakeAvatar.php`)*. Also I have tested `require_once`, still the problem is there.

Comment: @diEcho Also I mean of *"identical"* is *"all those identical black-images"*. And I have included `autoloader.php` into `classname.php`

Comment: you have included `autoloader.php` into `classname.php` then how `classname.php` can be called by `autoloader.php`? make sure to check with `realpath('../out/MakeAvatar.php')` inside classname.php

Comment: @diEcho Sorry, I said wrong. I have included `autoloader.php` into `home.php`. And this works `http://localhost/home` (makes correct avatars). But this doesn't work `http://localhost/home/classname` (makes unclear avatars)

Comment: so issue is with incorrect avatar not the file inclusion . right?

Comment: @diEcho Yeah .. seems so !!

Comment: @diEcho I got a new thing. The problem nothing to do with autoloader. I have edited my question. If you have some free times, please take a look at it.

Comment: It looks like the included file uses variables that are not available when you call it from the function. But there is no way to specify in more detail what it is. The code you gave seems to be irrelevant. The avatar creator code is the one that has problems.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes, The avatar creator code is the one that has problems. All I want to know, How can I use [this](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/3b1cd0a0acf86ab1601af5d16fbb415e) into a function?

Comment: `$spriteZ` is used as global in that avatar file.. you have to initialized it in your class?

Comment: @diEcho I initialized `global $spriteZ;` before `$obj = new classname();`. And it works perfectly. Is there any problem? Or will it be in future? `;-)` Or should I initialize it the other way? Or what I have done would be fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the code for the [`MakeAvatar.php`](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sajadshafizadeh/3b1cd0a0acf86ab1601af5d16fbb415e/raw/a7b9fcc2e6b4ae9d7c0adecab18e6ca2aa8eebe6/gistfile1.txt) file and seems like the issue is in the following code

```
/* generate sprite for corners and sides */
function getsprite($shape,$R,$G,$B,$rotation) {
    global $spriteZ;
```

The variable `$spriteZ` is defined in line #327 in the file. But when you include the file inside function this variable is *not* created as global variable but this is a variable inside a function. Check the [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) manual.

This means that inside `getsprite)` function the variable `$spriteZ` has `null` value because when the file is included inside a function there is no such global variable `$spriteZ` (it is not initialized as global variable). This is why the call to function `imagecreatetruecolor()` fails with error

> Warning: imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\inaccessible\identicon.php on line 7

I suggest to modify `getsprite()` and `getcenter()` functions and provide this variable as a parameter. Cause global variables might be very confusing.

p.s. The code architecture in general is not optimal but I guess this is out of scope of the question.

Comment: I have not seen the comment. But the trick is that it's not enough to initialize it in the class because even if you do it will not become global. You can initialize it before you create the class `$obj = new classname();`. This might allow you to do less changes in the code. But in this case you will have two variables with the same name.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if it is correct to make sure other people do not spend time on solving already solved question.

Comment: I initialized `global $spriteZ;` before `$obj = new classname();` *(as you said)*. And it works. Is there any problem? What do you mean *But in this case you will have two variables with the same name* ?

Comment: @stack I see several issues. 1. Using global variables is not the best idea. 2. When you include the file `MakeAvatar.php` something happens. This is not perfect too. I believe the code should be inside some function. 3. I think it might be a good idea to create a MakeAvatar class and define all logic in this class as class methods. In this case you do not need to include any file but create a class, define settings and call class method to create avatar. 4. You can ask a question if you will and I guess people might help you to build a better architecture. But this might be a lot of work.

Comment: @stack one more thing is how you pass parameters. You create a variable and then use it inside included file. This works but I believe this is not a great idea. Because it's not easy to guess what parameters should be specified.